# get count of all values of a variable in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a variable named "status" in which there are values like :
Expired
No Interest
Already Engaged
Never Reached
Non-Supported Market
Nurture

i want to get count of all these.

do i have to write manually like :

```
select 
sum (case when a.[Status Reason] ='Expired' and a.status='Disqualififed' then 1 else 0 end ) as expired,
sum (case when a.[Status Reason] ='No interest' and a.status='Disqualififed' then 1 else 0 end ) as nointerst from lead
```

is there any shortcut or some kind of automation possible

Comment: Are you asking how to do a [Dynamic Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404348/2029983)?

Comment: yes doing it dynamically without write sql for every value

Comment: Then the link should be all you need. :)